# PEAR SPREADSHEET EXCEL issue on writing local file

Tags: php, export-to-excel, pear

I have trouble on using PEAR on local file while trying to export data to Excel file.

This is the stack trace : 
 **Notice**: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/_test/vendor/pear/ole/OLE/PPS/File.php** on line **105**
 
 **Fatal error**: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/_test/vendor/pear/ole/OLE/PPS/File.php:106 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/_test/vendor/pear/ole/OLE/PPS/File.php(106): fopen('', 'w+b') #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/_test/vendor/pear/spreadsheet_excel_writer/Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer/Workbook.php(599): OLE_PPS_File->init() #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/_test/vendor/pear/spreadsheet_excel_writer/Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer/Workbook.php(576): Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Workbook->_storeOLEFile() #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/_test/vendor/pear/spreadsheet_excel_writer/Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer/Workbook.php(235): Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Workbook->_storeWorkbook() #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/_test/content/xls/xls_common.php(292): Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Workbook->close() #5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/_test/content/showcontent.php(439): require_once('/Applications/X...') #6 {main} thrown in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/_test/vendor/pear/ole/OLE/PPS/File.php** on line **106**
 It seems to be a permission case but I can't get rid of it.

I have modified the folder's permission in : pear/ole/OLE/PPS to allow both reading & writing but it didn't work. Besides, i'm not sure this is the correct path nor thing to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Xampp 8.2 with php 8 and mysql 8 on a mac.

Comment: look at phpinfo, check where the temp folder is  set,  change if necessary to a  folder where the web  server user (usually www-data) has permission

Comment: thx but where do I found this information in the phpinfo ?